# About the expression $27^{-\frac{x}{3}} +81^{\frac{1 -x}{4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The given expression 
>   $$27^{-\frac{x}{3}} +81^{\frac{1 -x}{4}}$$
>   can be stated as $a/b^x$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$. What is value of $a+b$?

I tried this question by substituting values for $x$ and got the answer. But I want proper solution for this. Please help me.

Comment: This is difficult to read. Can you please put the question in the question (not the title) and maybe use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I will post a picture of it

Comment: It is (27 raised to minus X upon 3) plus 81 raised    to (1 minus X upon 4)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $3^3=27$ and $3^4=81$, then 
$$27^{-\frac{x}{3}} +81^{\frac{1 -x}{4}}=3^{-x} +3^{1 -x}=3^{-x} +3^1\cdot 3^{-x}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I knew that one but how come 3×3 came from

Comment: Note that $3^{a+b}=3^a\cdot 3^b$.

Comment: @Atharva Shetty Any further doubt?

Comment: Then it happens to come as 3^ -x plus3 ×1/3^x then how to solve further sir

Comment: We want value for a+ b

Comment: Atharva Shetty Factor out $1/3^x$. What do you obtain?

Comment: I am not understanding it please give direct answer . I am a school going boy.

Comment: @Atharva Shetty I mean $1/3^{x} +3/3^{x}=(1 +3)/3^{x}$.

Comment: @Isham I prefer to give a hint, hoping that OP will conclude the exercise.

Comment: @Robert You are a good teacher very patient teacher indeed...best way to teach mathelmatics